# Verbose output of a migration to console or log

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, flyway

I've had a look around but can't seem to find an answer to this.

Our DBAs would like to see the output of sql migrations called by flyway.

In mysql for example:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE test (col INT);
```

Output gives:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

In oracle:

```
select 'Starting CREATE TEST TRIGGER' from DUAL;

/* Insert your code here */
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_TEST_TRIGGER
...
...

select 'Finished CREATE TEST TRIGGER' from DUAL;
```

Output would be something like:

```
'STARTINGCREATETESTTRIGGER
---------------------------
Starting CREATE TEST TRIGGER

....
....
Trigger created.

'FINISHEDCREATETESTTRIGGER
---------------------------
Finished CREATE TEST TRIGGER
```

Has anyone been able to solve this problem, or could anyone point me in the right direction?

Grateful for any ideas you may have.

Comment: Hi Axel, I've just found this as a possible solution to the oracle side of this. Would we be able to integrate this into Flyway perhaps.
[http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:45027262935845](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:45027262935845)